# How to make all my cart items have the same order ID when I check out?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, cart, shopping-cart

I'm trying to build a website with shopping cart functionality using java servlet and mysql. When multiple items are added to the cart, the user can either buy them separately or check out all at once. [image: Cart Page] However when the check out button is clicked, the cart items get added to my database but each of them have a different order ID.[image: image of my database table] I want all the cart items to have the same order ID, but I'm not sure how to code it.
This is my Cart class

```
public class Cart extends Product {
    private int quantity;

    public Cart() {
        
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
```

My Product class has attributes such as productID, productName, price etc.
This is my CheckOutServlet.The cart items are in a session object called cart_list. Here the cart items in the session are being put into an arraylist and are sent to the Dao class.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        ArrayList<Cart> cart_list = (ArrayList<Cart>)request.getSession().getAttribute("cart_list");
        Login user = (Login) request.getSession().getAttribute("name");
        user.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        LoginDao lg = new LoginDao();
        int idd = lg.getID(user);
        ArrayList<Order> checkout = new ArrayList<Order>();
        if(cart_list != null && user !=null) {
            for(Cart c:cart_list) {
                Order order = new Order();
                order.setProductID(c.getProductID());
                order.setUid(idd);
                order.setQuantity(c.getQuantity());
                order.setDate(formatter.format(date));
                checkout.add(order);
            }
            OrderDao od = new OrderDao();
            boolean res = od.insertMultiple(checkout);
            response.sendRedirect("orders.jsp");
        }else{
            if(user==null) {
                response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method in my dao class. I'm getting the arraylist of products from my servlet and adding them to my database one by one. Since they are being added one by one, each gets a different order ID. But I'm not sure how else I should insert them into the database, so that all the cart items get the same order ID.

```
public static boolean insertMultiple(ArrayList<Order> checkout) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    boolean result = false;
    for(Order o:checkout) {
        Connection connection = connector.getConnection();
        String query = "insert into orders(p_id,u_id,order_quantity,o_date) values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, o.getProductID());
        ps.setInt(2, o.getUid());
        ps.setInt(3, o.getQuantity());
        ps.setString(4, o.getDate());
        result = ps.executeUpdate() > 0;
        ps.close();
        connection.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Posting these here for more clarity. Everything works fine, I just want to know how to make all the cart items have the same order ID. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is order id a unique primary key in your mysql database?

Comment: Yes it is the primary key for the order table

Comment: I think you will have to restructure your table so that the order id is not the primary key if you want the order ids to be the same. Primary keys must be unique.

Comment: Ahh yes. That makes sense. So I can have another non primary-key column for the order id, but I'm still thinking about how to auto generate the same order ID for all cart items

Comment: You can have a counter in your insertMultiple() function and assign the same order id for all the products that you insert into the table.

Comment: Data model problem. You need orders and line items. `OrderID` should be a primary auto-generated key of the `orders` table, and a foreign key to that table in your `line_items` table.

Comment: Thank you for the answers @Kyriazis and user207421 :) I think I can use the mysql_insert_id() function to get the same order ID for all my cart items. I'll try it and see

Answer (score -1):

```java
public static boolean insertMultiple(ArrayList<Order> checkout) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    boolean result = false;
    for(Order o:checkout) {
        Connection connection = connector.getConnection();
        String query = "insert into orders(p_id,u_id,order_quantity,o_date, order_id) values(?,?,?,?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
        // get the highest order id
        int currentOrderId = ?; // you will have to figure out how to get the highest order id
        ps.setInt(1, o.getProductID());
        ps.setInt(2, o.getUid());
        ps.setInt(3, o.getQuantity());
        ps.setString(4, o.getDate());
        ps.setInt(5, currentOrderId++);
        result = ps.executeUpdate() > 0;
        ps.close();
        connection.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```